# Class or interface expected, What's wrong in this simple code?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

What is class or interface expected here, I don't know why it's giving me an error on line 4. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 15. I write a simple code and it's working but it's giving me an error of class or interface expected on line 4

```
package com.theyoo;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        String name = "Ayaz";
        System.out.println("Hello " + name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Go to File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and restart

Comment: I don't have installed InteliJ now so can't test it but your code looks fine. Maybe screenshot showing your project structure, code and error message could add some informations.

Answer (score -1):

I got it I just need to un-inject language/reference.

Comment: One of the great things about SO is that questions and answers are available for others, even years later. But that only works if they are good questions/answers. This answer makes no sense, and likely wouldn't help anybody in the future. Would you care to elaborate?